# Swap Fly PnL Payoff Question

Tags: swaption, payoff

Stuck on this payoff question. What is the PnL on 5s10s30s on a swap fly 10k 01, where the fly moves 8 to 26bp?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have 10k dv01 and the fly moves 18 bps (26 - 8), the PnL would be 180k, with the sign depending on whether you are long or short.

Comment: Question should be clarified. "the fly moves 8 to 26bp" means what? That it moved from 8bp to 26bp, or that it moved 8bp to 26bp?